# Sign a java applet with multiple certificates

Tags: java, applet, certificate

Is it possible sign a java applet with multiple certificates and if the JVM trusts at least one of them, the applet will load as expected?  ( in a browser ).

The use case is that we're migrating to a new certificate since ours is expiring, however it'd be ideal if *both* certificates could be considered valid, at least until the first certificate expires.

When I try to sign the applet with multiple certs, the JVM in the browser only seems to consider the most recent signing entry.

Comment: Did you ever find out if it was possible to dual sign? I'm searching for the answer too...

Answer (score 0):

I would rather try deploying two versions of the applet, and then use some javascript in the host page to dynamically load the correct version depending on system date and the date of your certificate switch-over.
See also [How can I embed a Java applet dynamically with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259328/how-can-i-embed-a-java-applet-dynamically-with-javascript) , and note the suggestion to use iframes.