# Running a Java function from a webpage?

Tags: java, javascript, html, bukkit

So my friend keeps making requests about this plugin I am writing for Bukkit and, like the decent person I am, I accept them. Unfortunately I am not that great of a programmer. I am making a help page for this plugin - A local file that comes with the plugin - and I need to know how I can run the .jar file of the plugin. I have the main class all ready, and they way I plan to do it is have something like this as part of the `<head></head>` tags.

```
<script> <!--
if(confirm("Would you like to run the plugin to set up first? (Click cancel if you do not)")) {
    //Something to run the plugin .jar file
}
//-->
</script>
```

Would this work? If I need to make any modifications, just let me know. I think I may only be able to call functions, in which case I will just call `main()`. 
NOTE: This works as-is, I just have it make another popup instead of running the .jar file. NOTE: Both the webpage and the jarfile are already downloaded onto the user's computer, I just need to be able to run it.
NOTE: This webpage is literally an HTML file that is downloaded to their computer when they download the plugin, and I want it to run my plugin because that it an automated setup function. The website is NOT hosted on a server. I feel like I REALLY need to clarify that. 
Looked through the code and decided that a link would be easiest and best for my purposes - Thanks for all the help! (By the way, it turned out that I would have the .jar file unpack the help document into the folder. Oh well :P)

Comment: Leave out the `else {}` bit -.-
Also, you can't run `.jar` files directly from JavaScript. Imagine the security issues with that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to leave out the `else{}`

Comment: @Cerbrus Actually, while you are right that you can't just run any jar file directly, it is very easy to run Java Applets. These applets, if signed correctly, even have access to your file system and can then launch another jar file. Also, you can make the launching of an arbitrary jar file possible (with security questions) using Java WebStart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing you can look into is the Java Web Start framework:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start

This allows users to launch an arbitrary jar file directly from their browsers and optionally install it on their machines. So, if all you are looking for is a way to deploy your Java program via a website, this might be the best solution.

In this scenario, the Java code would not run "inside" the browser (well, inside the JVM, but tied to the browser), like an applet would, but instead it would run as a standard separate process as if you had launched the jar file from your computer's hard-disk.

Comment: Wait, this seems perfect. Disregard my earlier comment, I hadn't scrolled down to this one yet.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example though? I can't figure out where to put this code. It worked by itself, but I need to know where to put it in on a real webpage. Sorry :P

Comment: Phew.... I haven't actually used it myself yet. I will be soon, that's why I read up on it already... But maybe this helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html (especially chapter 2 and 3) ?

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is to place a link: `<a href=http://www.MySite.com/app.jnlp>Launch the application</a>`. But you can get much more fancy than that to make sure all required plugins/JREs/etc. are installed. If the link is all you need, you can open it automatically from JavaScript with something along the lines of `window.location.href="http://www.MySite.com/app.jnlp"`...

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. So all I would need to do is determine the path of the .jar? And if so, can I do it like I do in Java? That is, `String path = System.getProperty('user.dir');` or something along the lines of that.
Also, do you know if it would be possible to call something that is saved as a .jar file?

Comment: @NickHartley If the jar file is already located on the user's computer, then you need to indeed find a way to get the location of it. You could, for example, prompt the user for it. But webstart is more meant for keeping the jar and jnlp files on the server along with your website. So, I would place it into a folder on in your webpage directory on the server and link there. Then the browser will download the jar to the user as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like I REALLY should have mentioned this before.... Both the webpage AND the .jar file are on the computer - the webpage comes in the same .zip file as the .jar file, in fact. They don't need to download the jar file, just click a link or a button to RUN it.
Again, sorry if I was being unclear. I'll try to remove "website" and replace it with "webpage", maybe that'll clear a bit of the confusion.

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense then... If they come in the same .zip file, you probably know the relative paths. So simply package the jnlp file in the same directory as your jar file and link to it with a relative link from the directory in which your page resides. For example, put the webpage (index.html) into the root folder of the zip and then have a subdirectory "app" and then simply do `<a href="app/myapp.jnlp">`. That should do the trick...

Comment: Ah, so relative directories work. That's awesome, and I think I'll do that. Thanks.
So just to make certain, it HAS to be a .jnlp file? That could cause problems what with it also being a bukkit plugin, as Bukkit can't read anything but .jar files. If it's possible to open a .jar file from a .jnlp then that would work.
Also, how do I make a .jnlp? Would I simply export it with that extension?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply put a static `<applet>` or `<object>` tag into your html page somewhere, it will always load your java code.

If you would instead like to load it dynamically later or give the user a choice about whether to load it or now, you can use the following construct in your JavaScript:

```
var app = document.createElement('applet');
app.archive= 'Java.jar';  // Your java jar file here
app.code= 'Java.class';   // Your Main class that extends Applet
app.width = '400';        // The size of the area for displaying ...
app.height = '10';        //   ... the applet's graphical output
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(app);
```

(Adapted from Beachhouse's answer here: [How can I embed a Java applet dynamically with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259328/how-can-i-embed-a-java-applet-dynamically-with-javascript); this uses the `<applet>` tag, but can be easily changed to using the `<object>` tag instead).

It is important that your Java code actually extends `java.applet.Applet`. Simply having a `main()` function isn't enough in this scenario. The `Applet` class then has methods you override (`init()`, `destroy()`, `start()`, and `stop()`), which get called automatically when your applet is loaded/unloaded/shown/hidden. You can also define public functions on the class that implements `Applet`, which you can then call on the `app` object from JavaScript directly. You might have to play around with this a little, because there are some differences in the types that Java and JavaScript use, so you can't just return or expect any type of parameter, but with a little trial and error (or reading up on the web), it works pretty well.

One thing you need to keep in mind is that it takes a while to load the applet. In fact, if the browser blocks the applet or the user clicks the no-button on the permission question, it might never get loaded. So you probably won't be able to call functions on the `app` object immediately. Instead, write yourself a little timer that checks periodically whether your applet has loaded. What I usually do is to define a `public boolean isReady()` function in my applet class and then use the following Javascript:

```
if (typeof app.isReady=='undefined') return false;
return app.isReady();
```

But, of course, if you are only using the `init()` and `start()` methods without calling the applet from Javascript, you won't have to worry about this.

Comment: Great answer, but I'm not too sure if it answers my question... I meant getting the webpage - a file downloaded onto their computer when the plugin is downloaded - running the .jar file separately from the webpage. Also, how exactly would I implement the `<object>` tags, if it allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for `<applet>` tag here.

```
<APPLET code="MyJAVAFile.jar"></APPLET>
```

For HTML5, you should use `<object>` tag, something like this:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" code="MyJAVAFile.jar"></object>
```

You might also find [this article](https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/HTML5_APPLETS/) interesting. Worth reading.

Comment: The `<applet>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use the `<object>` tag instead. Also, the `<applet>` element is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Comment: Would the `<object>` tag function in the same way? That is, `<object code="javaFile.jar"></object>`?

Comment: It is Pretty much the same, just more generall